# Mean of 그 모든 길은 널 향한 거야 in a deeper sense?

Tags: translation, hangul

What does ‘그 모든 길은 널 향한 거야’ mean in English? I saw the pronunciation of it, but the translation from Korean to English sounds off. If anyone knows please let me know. Also, a better way to pronounce it.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context about where you heard this (to help with the specifics of the deeper sense in which it might be meant)?

Comment: 'All roads lead to you'. What did you get as your translation and what's the context for this?

Comment: Well, I assume it should have been 그 모든 길은 널 **향하는** 거야. Not a few people are insensitive to the difference between -ㄴ (relative past for a verb; relative present for an adjective) and -는 (relative present for a verb). Literally, the sentence means "All those ways are in the direction of you." For pronunciation, people do not emphasize the ㅎ sound enough although they have to. 널 향한 would sound like [널 향안], [너량안] and [널량안] that are *incorrect* but common.

Answer (score 1):

Literally, "All roads lead to you". As a metaphor, it would mean something like "It's all about you"; "Everything I do is for you". It would be rare as a spoken sentence. You might find it in a song referring to someone that the singer wants to express their love for.